# Azure Devops Pipeline - PublishPipelineArtifact@1 - ##[error]Unable to load symbolic/hard linked file

Tags: php, laravel, azure-devops

Hellow

Gettging the following error when publishing the pipeline artifacts

*##[error]Unable to load symbolic/hard linked file. Check 'fsutil behavior query SymlinkEvaluation' to ensure proper behavior.*

**Pipeline (PHP Laravel artifacts)**

> ## PHP
>
> ## Test and package your PHP project.
>
> ## Add steps that run tests, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
>
> ## https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/php
>
> trigger:
>
> - master
>
> pool:   vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
>
> variables:   phpVersion: 7.2
>
> steps:
>
> - script: |
>   sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php$(phpVersion)
>   sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar$(phpVersion)
>   sudo update-alternatives --set phpdbg /usr/bin/phpdbg$(phpVersion)
>   sudo update-alternatives --set php-cgi /usr/bin/php-cgi$(phpVersion)
>   sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar$(phpVersion)
>   php -version   displayName: 'Use PHP version $(phpVersion)'
> - script: |
>   sudo composer self-update
>   composer global require laravel/installer
>   composer update --no-interaction --prefer-dist --no-suggest
>   composer --version
>   'Deploy Laravel'
> - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1   inputs:
>   targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
>   artifact: 'PriVet_Backend_$(Build.BuildId)'
>   publishLocation: 'pipeline'

**From the logs:**

2020-07-01T08:13:09.8456382Z Error, System.IO.FileLoadException: Unable to load symbolic/hard linked file.  Check 'fsutil behavior query SymlinkEvaluation' to ensure proper behavior. 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8457580Z  ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '/home/vsts/work/1/s/www/vendor/amphp/parallel-functions/docs/asset'. 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8458469Z File name: '/home/vsts/work/1/s/www/vendor/amphp/parallel-functions/docs/asset' 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8459102Z    at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter) 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8459726Z    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode) 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8460360Z    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options) 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8461407Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.FileStreamUtils.OpenFileStreamForAsync(String filePath, FileMode mode, FileAccess fileAccess, FileShare fileShare, FileOptions extraOptions) 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8462269Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.ChunkerHelper.CreateFromFileAsync(IFileSystem fileSystem, String path, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean configureAwait) 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8463250Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.FileBlobDescriptor.CalculateAsync(IFileSystem fileSystem, String rootDirectory, Boolean chunkDedup, String relativePath, FileBlobType fileBlobType, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8464322Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.PrecomputedHashesGenerator.GetFileBlobDescriptorAsync(String rootDirectory, Boolean chunkDedup, PageItem pageItem, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8465253Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.PrecomputedHashesGenerator.GetFileBlobDescriptorAsync(String rootDirectory, Boolean chunkDedup, PageItem pageItem, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8466173Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.PrecomputedHashesGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<<PaginateAndProcessFilesHelperAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8467610Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8468136Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.NonSwallowingActionBlock.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<b__0>d.MoveNext() 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8468799Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8469476Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.PrecomputedHashesGenerator.PaginateAndProcessFilesHelperAsync(String sourceDirectory, Boolean chunkDedup, IEnumerable`1 pathsInDir, Action`1 hashCompleteCallback, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8470201Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.PrecomputedHashesGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext() 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8529135Z Information, 7472 files processed. 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8542251Z Information, 7572 files processed. 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8546157Z Information, 7672 files processed. 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8569555Z Information, 7772 files processed. 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8596993Z Information, 7872 files processed. 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8633894Z Information, 7972 files processed. 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8643831Z Information, 8072 files processed. 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8664592Z Information, 8172 files processed. 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8664847Z Information, 8272 files processed. 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8665070Z Information, 8372 files processed. 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8665268Z Information, 8472 files processed. 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8665472Z Information, 8572 files processed. 2020-07-01T08:13:09.8667556Z Information, 8672 files processed. 2020-07-01T08:13:11.7076135Z Information, ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender correlated 2 events with X-TFS-Session f56bb233-a941-4e13-97dc-2efe60c398fe 2020-07-01T08:13:11.7128821Z ##[error]Unable to load symbolic/hard linked file.  Check 'fsutil behavior query SymlinkEvaluation' to ensure proper behavior. 2020-07-01T08:13:11.7138924Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]Unable to load symbolic/hard linked file.  Check 'fsutil behavior query SymlinkEvaluation' to ensure proper behavior. 2020-07-01T08:13:11.7153064Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;] 2020-07-01T08:13:11.7158800Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.PrecomputedHashesGenerator.GetFileBlobDescriptorAsync(String rootDirectory, Boolean chunkDedup, PageItem pageItem, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.PrecomputedHashesGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.NonSwallowingActionBlock.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<<CreateNonSwallowingFunc>b__0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.PrecomputedHashesGenerator.PaginateAndProcessFilesHelperAsync(String sourceDirectory, Boolean chunkDedup, IEnumerable`1 pathsInDir, Action`1 hashCompleteCallback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.PrecomputedHashesGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<<PaginateAndProcessFiles>b__0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.ExceptionExtensions.ReThrow(Exception ex)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.PrecomputedHashesGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<<PaginateAndProcessFiles>b__0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.NonSwallowingActionBlock.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<b__0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.PrecomputedHashesGenerator.PaginateAndProcessFiles(String sourceDirectory, Boolean chunkDedup, IEnumerable`1 pages, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action`1 hashCompleteCallback)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.WebApi.DedupManifestArtifactClient.PublishAsync(String fullPath, ArtifactPublishOptions artifactPublishOptions, String manifestFileOutputPath, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Agent.Plugins.PipelineArtifact.PipelineArtifactServer.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<b__1>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.Telemetry.BlobStoreClientTelemetry.MeasureActionAsync[TResult](BlobStoreTelemetryRecord record, Func`1 actionAsync)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.ExceptionExtensions.ReThrow(Exception ex)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.BlobStore.Common.Telemetry.BlobStoreClientTelemetry.MeasureActionAsync[TResult](BlobStoreTelemetryRecord record, Func`1 actionAsync)    at Agent.Plugins.PipelineArtifact.PipelineArtifactServer.UploadAsync(AgentTaskPluginExecutionContext context, Guid projectId, Int32 pipelineId, String name, String source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Agent.Plugins.PipelineArtifact.PublishPipelineArtifactTaskV1.ProcessCommandInternalAsync(AgentTaskPluginExecutionContext context, CancellationToken token)    at Agent.PluginHost.Program.Main(String[] args) 2020-07-01T08:13:11.7255180Z ##[section]Finishing: PublishPipelineArtifact

Comment: For a start, can you please apply some more formatting to your question?

Comment: Hi Did you checked if original file which the symbolic file linked existed? See below answer for more information.

Answer (score 0):

When PublishPipelineArtifact task publishes a folder which contains a symbolic link. It does not preserve the symlink file. Instead the original file(that the symbolic link points to) will be copied in the artifact.

From above error of yours, It looks like the original file which the symbolic file `/home/vsts/work/1/s/www/vendor/amphp/parallel-functions/docs/asset` points cannot be found.

You can run  `ls -l symboliclink` n a bash task (ie.`ls -l $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/www/vendor/amphp/parallel-functions/docs/asset`) to check where the symbolic link points to. And make sure the origin file exists.

If the files in folder `/home/vsts/work/1/s/www/vendor/amphp/parallel-functions/docs/asset` can be omitted in the Artifacts. You can add a [.artifactignore file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/reference/artifactignore?view=azure-devops) in the same directory as defined as target path to ignore the symbolic file and its contents.